# rebar3: console not opening

Tags: erlang

This is a rebar3 release compiled and released without any error. (There was this line ( ===> Missing beam file elf_format <<"/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-3.11.3/ebin/elf_format.beam">>) I guess that's something else).

There is a line in the error which says that there is another link using the same hostname. Seeing this I deleted all such projects of the same name and recompiled and re released.

Also when i try start option no output is shown and localhost:8080 is not started.(I have been trying to do the example on this link in rebar3  :- http://jordenlowe.com/title/Explain_like_I_am_5_-_Erlang_REST_Framework_Cowboy)

What is/could be the reason for this error.
[image: Output of trying to open the console]

Answer (score 2):

The main error is: `the name hello_erlang@you_host seems to be in use by another Erlang node` which says that there is another running Erlang node with the same name. You can see a list of running Erlang node with following [Erlang Port Mapper Daemon](http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) (epmd) command:

```
 epmd -names
```

You must stop or kill currently running node with the desired node name and then start the new one.

Comment: I did this and though did not completely understand what i did, killed some processes and it worked.
Thanks. :)